# getHibernateTemplate() return String

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am using this and getting an error like:

Incompatible types:
Required: String
Found:List

I have a table with few columns and I want to return a phone when the name and address match.

```
@Override
public String getphone(long name,String address){
     String phone= getHibernateTemplate().find("from Table where name=" + name+"AND address='" + address+"'");
        return phone;
    }
```

Comment: The method `find()` returns a `List`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to return a String. What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: As a comment I think you should use parameterized strings, not concating it inside the query

Comment: Can you please explain further I am new to hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `find` method of `HibernateTemplate`, return the `List<?>`

```
public List<?> find(final String queryString, final Object... values) throws DataAccessException {

}
```

You need to access the elements of List or say 1st element and return that.

```
@Override  
public String getphone(long name,String address){ 
     List<EntityABC> entityList = getHibernateTemplate().find("from Table where name=" + name+"AND address='" + address+"'");

if(null!=entityList && entityList.size() >0){
     return phoneNumberList.get(0).getPhone();
}

return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override  
public String getphone(long name,String address){ 
     String phone= getHibernateTemplate().find("from Table where name=" + name+"AND address='" + address+"'").get(0).getPhone();
     return phone;
}
```

I think this can solve your problem